# Higgs field shielding possibility

Tags: higgs

Is it possible for a place to exist with zero Higgs field, by kind of shielding it or something(theoretically)?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no, though as always the answer is more involved than this.

I would guess you are thinking of the way that a [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) can block electromagnetic fields. However the Higgs field is a [quantum field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory) and this is very different from an electromagnetic field. A quantum field is a mathematical object that is present everywhere in spacetime and describes how fundamental particles behave. Quantum fields cannot be screened out because they are not a physical thing.

Comment: Can we stop it's interaction with matter? (To make it massless)

Comment: @Saptarshisarma: No. The quantum fields exist at all points in spacetime and cannot be removed, screened out or whatever. It is impossible to prevent the particle fields from interacting with the Higgs field.

Comment: But what about a photon?

Comment: @Saptarshisarma: the photon is part of the Higgs field, or more precisely part of the unified EW gauge degrees of freedom. It's the bit that got left over when the EW symmetry broke and three of the degrees of freedom acquired masses.

Comment: @Saptarshisarma Also, the Higgs mechanism is only responsible for a small percentage of the mass of matter. Even if you could somehow block the Higgs field, that would *not* make atoms massless.

Comment: I downvoted this because isn't the electromagnetic field also a quantum field? and therefore this seems to explain nothing.

Comment: @user253751 An electromagnetic field is not a quantum field. It is a state of a quantum field - specifically the photon quantum field - just as a Higgs boson is a state of the Higgs quantum field. You can certainly screen an electromagnetic field field, but that is not what the question is asking. You cannot screen out a quantum field i.e. you cannot screen off some region of spacetime such that the quantum field does not exist inside that region. All you could do is have the quantum field be in its ground state inside the region, which is effectively what you do when you screen an EM field.

Comment: @JohnRennie surley Higgs boson is to Higgs quantum field as photon (not electromagnetic field) is to photon field?

Comment: @user253751 An electromagnetic field is constructed from virtual photons (which don't really exist, but that's another story :-) so it is a state of the photon quantum field.

Comment: @user253751 Next time you might consider asking first and down-voting second. All of us who post answers here are doing it to try and make life better for people studying physics. There are no financial rewards - we do it out of good will. If you're uncertain about some aspect of an answer just ask and the author will generally be happy to discuss it.